# Composing a new graphic in R with magick from multiple existing images

Tags: r, imagemagick

I've created a table with the excellent `gt` package. Since it was a long table, my code creates the table in two halves. I save both halves to disk as png files then use the `magick` package's `image_append()` to composite them side-by-side as a new png file. All good.

Now, with `magick`, I'd like to compose a final graphic with a logo, some title text and source notes using `image_annotate()`, and my saved table, all laid out nicely.

I'm stuck trying to understand the right way to do that. I have all the graphical pieces, but I don't know how to create new, blank graphic with `magick` and then lay those pieces out in the locations I want them so that the finished product looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you post your individual images and lay it out in say GIMP or the like so that we can see what you want. Then I can give you the commands in command line Imagemagick to do that. Sorry I do not know R. To create a new 500x500 blank image, say white, you would do `convert -size 500x500 xc:white new_image.png` or `convert -size 500x500 canvas:white new_image.png`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @fmw42. I've updated the post with an image to show what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to create text images in Imagemagick. But here is likely the easiest for you to use and convert to R. The following is command line Imagemagick.

**Logo:**

[image]

**Table Text Image:**

[image]

**Steps:** (In subsequent command)

```
 - Line 1: load imagemagick convert
 - Line 2: create 500x500 white background image
 - Line 3: insert the logo image at +20+20 relative to top left
 - Line 4: add title text via -annotate
 - Line 5: add sub-title text via -annotate
 - Line 6: insert the preformed table image below those
 - Line 7: add the source notes text via -annotate
 - Line 8: save the resulting png file to disk
```

**Command:**

```
convert \
-size 500x500 xc:white \
rainbow_logo.png -gravity northwest -geometry +20+20 -compose over -composite \
-font arial -fill black -pointsize 48 -annotate +125+15 "TITLE TEXT" \
-font arial -fill black -pointsize 32 -annotate +125+65 "SUB-TITLE TEXT" \
lorem.png -gravity northwest -geometry +20+140 -compose over -composite \
-font arial -fill black -pointsize 18 -annotate +20+455 "SOURCE NOTES" \
result2.png
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the algorithm, @fmw42. Going to see if I can make this happen with the R interface provided via the `magick` package or whether I need to run a shell script instead.